# Are questions about languages, libraries and databases on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Certain languages such as R and libraries/platforms such as Hadoop are used almost exclusively in data science. Should programming or configuration based questions for such languages, databases, libraries be on-topic?

Answer (score 6):

I would say, questions pertaining to programming languages and tools *as they are used in data science* are relevant.  Certainly I could ask a question about those tools that would be off topic, e.g. "Why is Hadoop's logo an elephant?"

A distinct but related question to "is it on topic" is "is this the *best* site for it"?  The best site might depend on whether it's primarily a question about R as a programming language (stackoverflow), or primarily a question about statistical analysis using R as an example (crossvalidated), or primarily about R as a tool for data science (here).

[Is the R language suitable for big data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41/is-the-r-language-suitable-for-big-data) seems like a good question for DataScience.

[Removal of statistically significant intercept term boosts R2 in linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-boosts-r2-in-linear-model) seems at home in Cross Validated, but might be on topic here as well.

[How to sort a dataframe by column(s) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r) seems a good fit for stackoverflow.

But many questions might be at home on multiple sites.  I don't think the fact that a question could also be asked elsewhere necessarily means it's off-topic here.